# In Postgis how to construct Geojson from a one to many relationship between a spatial table and a related (non spatial) table

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a spatial table of hospitals (points) that has a one to many relationship with a (non spatial) table of valences (cirurgy, urgency, etc.)

**hospital** (id, name, geom);
**valence** (id, name, valence)

"name" is the common field.

How to construct in PostgreSQL/Postgis a valid Geojson from this, where each hospital (point) can have one or many valences?

I had already tried some variations of this query, but always giving the same error of "more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression".

```
SELECT row_to_json(fc) FROM 
( 
    SELECT 'FeatureCollection' As type, array_to_json(array_agg(f)) As features from

    (
    SELECT 'Feature' As type, ST_AsGeoJSON(lg.geom)::json As geometry, row_to_json

        ((select l from (select
        v.*
                FROM valence v
                inner join hospital lg  on lg."name" =  v."name" ) As l   
        )) As properties
        from hospital as lg)

     As f 
)  As fc;
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this query, the list of "valences" is returned as a json array in the property `properties.valences`

```
SELECT
  json_build_object(
    'type', 'FeatureCollection',
    'features', json_agg(
      json_build_object(
        'type', 'Feature',
        'geometry', ST_AsGeoJSON(h.geom)::json,
        'properties', json_build_object(
          'name', h.name,
          'valences', (
            -- Generate json array of "valences":
            SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(v.valence)) 
            FROM valence v 
            WHERE v.name = h.name 
            GROUP BY v.name
          )
        )
      ) 
    )
  ) json
FROM
  hospital h
```

The returned GeoJSON object is valid according to http://geojsonlint.com/